Lettuce mod library omitting null values and mis aligning key value pairs for FT.Search command result
I am implementing ft.search command using lettuce mod in redis json. below is the raw query -
FT.SEARCH idx:accountproject '@siteId:[1 1] @status:{A} @premises:{ON}' RETURN 9 id accountId siteId addressAddress1 addressAddress2 addressCity addressStateProvince addressPostalCode addressCountry LIMIT 0 1

and it returns below response -
1) "4391"
2) "accpro:100"
3) 1) "id"
   2) "100"
   3) "accountId"
   4) "500"
   5) "siteId"
   6) "1"
   7) "addressAddress1"
   8) "6******"
   9) "addressAddress2"
   10) "null"
   11) "addressCity"
   12) "F******"
   13) "addressStateProvince"
   14) "FL"
   15) "addressPostalCode"
   16) "33351"
   17) "addressCountry"
   18) "null"

While I try to same via java lettuce library, then I get below response -
{id=100, accountId=500, siteId=1, addressAddress1=6*****, addressAddress2=addressCity, F********=addressStateProvince, FL=addressPostalCode, 33351=addressCountry}

Here addressAddress2 is having incorrect value, and the following keys.. It is happening because of mis handling of null values in lettuce library.
Below is my redis client setup -
    final RedisURIBuilder uriBuilder = new RedisURIBuilder()
        .host(host)
        .port(port)
        .password(password);
    RedisModulesClient redisModulesClient = RedisModulesClient.create(uriBuilder.build());
    redisModulesClient.setOptions(
        ClientOptions.builder()
            .timeoutOptions(
                TimeoutOptions.builder().timeoutCommands(true).fixedTimeout(commandTimeOut).build())
            .protocolVersion(ProtocolVersion.RESP2)
            .socketOptions(SocketOptions.builder().connectTimeout(connectionTimeOut).build())
            .build());

Redis Index -
FT.CREATE
    idx:accountproject ON JSON
        PREFIX 1 accpro:
    SCHEMA
        $.id AS id TAG
        $.accountId AS accountId NUMERIC SORTABLE
        $.siteId AS siteId NUMERIC SORTABLE
        $.status AS status TAG SORTABLE
        $.premises AS premises TAG SORTABLE
        $.accountType AS accountType TAG SORTABLE

        $.location.coordinates AS locationCoordinates NUMERIC
        $.location.type AS locationType TAG 
        $.address.address1 AS addressAddress1 TAG
        $.address.address2 AS addressAddress2 TAG
        $.address.city AS addressCity TAG
        $.address.stateProvince AS addressStateProvince TAG
        $.address.postalCode AS addressPostalCode TAG
        $.address.country AS addressCountry TAG

Lettuce mod version 4.1.0
Lettuce core version 6.3.2.RELEASE
Please kindly help me in resolving this null handling issue in lettuce.
Lettuce issue # 59 : https://github.com/redis/lettucemod/issues/59

Move to ValKey-Glide less buggy, more stable, direct support.

Im actually trying to help but find it a bit hard to reproduce. If you can share the index you use and a json sample id be able to help much more.

@avifen - I have updated the index schema in the description, kindly try to reproduce the issue.

On it. theres a reason you use resp2?

and can you add example of a json?

Take any random values, but just keep address2 as null.

No particular reason for resp2, but I also tried with resp3 and it worked weirdly and it returned empty result document in response, so I switched back to resp2.

Generally you should use 3, and try to understand the issues and how to deal with them. It's going to be 4 sooner or later and your app will lose connection with the updates.

I didn't forget you, a bit bussy, but meanwhile, if you can give me a ready Json it will help because something is failing on jsons I generate.

@avifen do checkout the github issues link in the description, this appears like bug fix has been recently implemented.

Yea seems like it, maybe you can start use their pre-release version.

My direction was to try to find a way to hook the response and bypass their parsing, cause obviously it's a bug, but its take some effort to dive into the code
